# How to read a line from a text file and use it as an input

Tags: python, file, input, output

I am writing a program to execute a couple of commands on the network switches. The code basically asks the user to input the IP address of the network node and then it telnets into it and executes the commands. I have made that code to work. Now, suppose if there are 100+ switches that I need to run the commands on, I will have to run the script 100+ times. I was thinking maybe I could put the list of IP address, one each line, on the text file and then code actually reads the first line (IP Addres) put that address as an input to telnet  into the switch which in turns telnets into the switch and then moves to the next line in the text file, till the end of file. The following is what I intend to use:

Text file

172.16.1.1

172.16.1.2

172.16.1.3

172.16.1.4

..........

..........

172.16.1.254

I am thinking of using the below code

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(['myfile']):
    do_something(line)
```

So what variable type should I use for each line it reads and then takes that as input and then executes the code.

Thank you
A

Comment: It would be useful to state what language you are using or tag it

Comment: I am using Python as coding language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the `open` function to open a file, then iterate through it by line:

```
with open("your_file.txt") as file:
     for line in file:
          do_something(line)
```

If you wanted to store these IP addresses first (and you probably should), you can just include them in a list (`your_list = []`), and replace `do_something(line)` with `your_list.append(line)`.

Keep in mind that you'd probably want to do some sort of validation on each line to make sure it was only numbers and not spaces, whitespace characters, letters, etc. You could easily do this like so:

```
 formatted_line = ''.join([a for a in line if a.isdigit() or a == '.'])
```

This creates a list of each digit character, then uses `join` to add each letter in order back into a string. Note that this assumes you're only using IPv4 addresses - if you're using v6 you'd want to use different formatting logic.

The type you store the IP address in is entirely dependent on what you want to do with that (and you haven't told us that), but I think for most purposes you'd be best off leaving it as a string.